# How to run compiled blazor web client from command line?

Tags: c#, command-line, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Let's say I have classic blazor projects -- server, client, and shared. I can set server as startup project in VS 2019 and run it (it will run server). Or I can set client as a startup project and run it (it will run client). So far, so good.

I can switch to command line, navigate to "bin" folder of server and execute "dotnet WebBlazor.Server.dll", server will run as I expected it.

But when I navigate to client folder I can see dll is placed in two places -- next to "wwwroot" folder and inside "wwwroot/_framework" folder along with other dlls. When I try to execute "dotnet WebBlazor.Client.dll" (in both mentioned places) I got error stating there is no such file as WebBlazor.Client.deps.json. and also that 'hostpolicy.dll' library is missing.

Futher error message directs me into two choices that I should run web client as self-contained app or framework-dependent app. All I would like to do is to run client -- if I am not mistaken in server case Kestrel is run automatically and on top of tip the server code I write. I assumed this is the case also with the client, so I would like to run it in CLI as VS is able to run it.

*I am not publishing my app yet, I just want to run compiled binaries from CLI.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your client project folder, launch :

```sh
dotnet run
```

Comment: Many thanks, I added `--no-build` option to skip the building, but now I am curious what the devils sits behind it that this call works and running directly client dll does not.

Comment: @astrowalker Your wasm app references WebAssembly.DevSever nuget - which is kestrel with some default configuration. Also, you don't have to use VS play button all the time. Try out dotnet watch run command.

Comment: I'm working with an existing Blazor project using IIS. What would keep the browser from opening up? I assume IIS is not starting because when I debug from VS the browser opens and the app loads. When I run from the CLI I get a connection failed error on the same port that VS opens.

Comment: @juicebyjustin configure the [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0&preserve-view=true#development-and-launchsettingsjson) for your convenience.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the original question, "I just want to run compiled binaries from CLI". I also want to run the COMPILED code from the PUBLISH folder. How do I do that? I will copy-paste the PUBLISH folder in to few of my local machines and RUN the WASM on those machine fromcommand line.

Comment: @MehdiAnis he said you don't publish it so that answer ! Blazor WASM run in the browser there isn't command line to run it. You need first to deploy it to an HTTP Server and browse it. Read that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-8.0#standalone-deployment