# How to run published Blazor web client from the folder?

Tags: blazor, publish, blazor-webassembly

This question might be seen as follow-up of my previous one: [How to run compiled blazor web client from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114346/how-to-run-compiled-blazor-web-client-from-command-line)

I have correctly written Blazor web client (solution with only single project), I can run it from Visual Studio or from command line.

Now I published the project to the folder and I would like to run it from that folder -- the thing is all content is placed in "wwwroot/_framework" subfolder and I don't see server code needed for running all this stuff.

So how I make VS to publish server needed as well?

*In short I would like to get all the files needed, so I can type "dotnet myapp.dll" or something like this, server will start with my blazor app. Exactly what happens when I run it from VS.*

Comment: A WebAssembly application has no server code. If you open `index.html` in a browser, it will load the WASM application and execute it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I understand "webasm" is client code, but the project contains DevServer nuget and the project is runnable for sure, because I can run it. So I am asking how to "pack" it all together and run it after publish as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can run it through IIS or Docker and something like Nginx.